# What is civicrm basic structure?

Tags: php, crm

Hi what is civicrm basic structure. which architecture they are using?

Comment: read in there site like http://civicrm.org/node/91

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the architecture series:

http://civicrm.org/architecture

gives lots of detail on code structure and design

lobo